# id of ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

How can i set the id of ui:repeat

Structure of my code is

```
Tabview
  ui : repeat 
     dattable
       column
          checkbox
```

I am getting the id of checkbox as

```
tabViewId:0:j_idt45:0:dataTableId:0:checkBoxId
```

It contains 7 things which are

```
id of tabview
active tab
ui:repeat id
index of ui:repeat
id of dattable
row of dattable
id of checkbox
```

i want to assign id of ui:repeat so that it does not chooses it on its own.

How can i set the id of ui:repeat, say

```
repeatId
```

instead of `j_idt45`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try:

```
<ui:repeat id="repeatId" ...
```

(it is [undocumented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) but it works in both Mojarra and MyFaces).

Comment: Thanks Adam :) :) :) . It worked. But this kind of things should be properly documented.

Comment: Just to note: I've tried to use this combined with `<ui:repeat varStatus="val">`. In one of the components inside `<ui:repeat>` i had `id="value#{val.index}"`. Unfortunately the `ValueExpression` is not evaluated and the result is only `value`.

Comment: Nice idea. But did not work in Primefaces 6.0 (JSF 2.2)?  Any help please?

Comment: This also works in MyFaces. I edited to add that fact.

Comment: Whoa. Nice one. Works in JSF 2.2 using PF 7.0.